# I want to know how to use the sumifs in Excel VBA if the criteria is a wildcard variable

Tags: excel

Here is my formula the gets an error

my data array  is on a sheet called Deposit!F7:F230
My criteria array is on a sheet called Deposit!B7:B230
My criteria is on a cells AC239 of Sheet "Others"
I want to put the formula on Sheets("Others").Range("AC436")
The criteria is a text, like Down. So what I want is so sum all amount on Deposit!F7:F230, for all description with the word "Down" on the colum Deposit!B7:B230.

The criteria is on AC239 that will change from time to time

The formula that I want to build on Excel VBa is

Sheets("Others").Range("AE436").Formula = "=SUMIFS(Deposit!F7:F230,Deposit!B7:B230,"*"&AC239&"*")"

It works on the cell, if I write this down directly on the cell, however, when I transfer to Excel VBA it does not work

On Excel VBA module the outcome is like this and does not work
Sheets("Others").Range("AE436").Formula = "=SUMIFS(Deposit!F7:F230,Deposit!B7:B230," * "&AC239&" * ")"

Any help will be grealy appreciated

I was expecting that the below line in VBA Excel would work

Sheets("Others").Range("AE436").Formula = "=SUMIFS(Deposit!F7:F230,Deposit!B7:B230," * "&AC239&" * ")"

Comment: `"=SUMIFS(Deposit!F7:F230,Deposit!B7:B230,""*""&AC239&""*"")"`